# __enter__ , __exit__ , with block is not working

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to execute this code , it returns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "with.py", line 13, in <module>
    with A as a:
AttributeError: __enter__"
```

I searched and found that this error occurs when I haven't define `__enter__` or `__exit__`  methods. but I defined both, and still getting this error

```
class A:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.t='printing from enter variable t'
        return self.t

    def fun(self):
        print("inside fun")
        print(self.t)

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        print("exiting.........")
        print(exception_type, exception_value, traceback)

with A as a:
    a.fun()
```

Comment: you are calling a non-existent function fn()

Comment: You need to use an instance of `A ` not the class itself. `with A() as a:` although you'll still have problems because `a` will be the string returned from your `__enter__` method.

Comment: thats a typing mistake when i was typing in stackoverflow. i edited. now pls tell me. what is the problem here?

Comment: Holloway thanks. I understand what you've said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong here. The error message you are getting is because you are trying to use the class itself as a context manager instead of an instance.

```
with A() as a: # uses an instance of A
```

instead of

```
with A as a: # uses the class A
```

The class A has no `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods as it is an instance of `type`.

The second is that `a` will be bound to the return value of the `__enter__` method, in this case the string.

A string has no `fun` method so will raise an attribute error. I imagine you want to `return self` from your `__enter__` method.

Comment: Holloway thanks for helping.. It worked!! and I came to know how it is working by your comment :)